# How to increment ID number of JSON file in Angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I need to increment ID number by one each time I save a new item in my app. Here is the Plunker code

```
<a>http://plnkr.co/edit/mD8384G9vsHokdWcc5P7?p=preview</a>
```

I tried all sorts of increment functions but I dont know how to set that the value constantly changes everytime I click save and that the first saved thing have id=1, second id=2 etc.

Note: This is not a duplicate question I tried all solutions from Stackoverflow and none of it worked for me s o please dont report or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are

```
$scope.model.id = $scope.vm.sites.length+1;
```

Comment: if you delete some rows in between, you would end up generating duplicate ids